# Web application (asp.net) and SQL Server good practice question

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I have very little experience when it comes to web application and SQL Server. I am trying to develop a web app for my team that will basically replace the Excel spreadsheet that we use right now.

The current Excel spreadsheet has 5 tabs with tables. I would like to configure the app the same way. so here is my question.

Is it better to load from the database all the tables at once put everything in some `IEnumerible`, and then use one page with some tabs so we can easily navigate between the tables (like Excel).

Or is it better to just load the first table in the home page and then load the data from the server when the next page is open...and so one for the others pages...Hope I am clear :-)

The tables are not huge 20-30 rows of maybe 10 columns...

Comment: For tables that size it really doesn't matter. I suggest you build your app first then optimise

Comment: Thank you, I'll go with the tab for now

Comment: I would load when you click on a given tab - but keep that data persisted, then when you flip or change between tabs - you get as good or even better then desktop performance and experience for the user.